# Problemas para incluir Razor ASP.NET MVC en envío de correo

Tags: mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Estoy implementando en mi controlador en la acción **create** al momento de crear un nuevo registro para enviar un correo.

Simplemente es una tabla en *HTML* con *CSS*, pero quiero incluir los datos del usuario con *Razor* en la plantilla. En las columnas de la tabla quiero incluir el objeto candidato con *Razor*, pero al colocar **@candidato.nombre**, lo reconoce como texto. He intentado concatenar con **+** el *HTML*, más la tabla, sin embargo tampoco funciona.

Código:

```html
public ActionResult Fiscalia([Bind(Include = "CandidatoId,PosicionId,Nombre,Telefono,Correo,Profesion,Puesto,Propuesto,Comentario,Fecpostula")] Candidato candidato, string mensaje)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        candidato.Fecpostula = DateTime.Now;
        var id = 7;
        candidato.PosicionId = id;
        db.Candidatoes.Add(candidato);
        db.SaveChanges();
        if (candidato.CandidatoId > 0)
        {

            //Logica para enviar correo
            var message = new MailMessage
            {
                Subject = "Notificación Postulación de Candidatos Nuevo Mensaje de :" + " " + candidato.Propuesto,

                Body =
                  @"
<html lang=""en"">
  <head>    
    <meta content=""text/html; charset=utf-8"" http-equiv=""Content-Type"">
    <title>
        Notificacion
    </title>
    <style type=""text/css"">
        HTML{background-color: #e8e8e8;}
        .courses-table{font-size: 12px; padding: 3px; border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0;}
        .courses-table .description{color: #505050;}
        .courses-table td{border: 1px solid #D1D1D1; background-color: #F3F3F3; padding: 0 10px;}
        .courses-table th{border: 1px solid #424242; color: #FFFFFF;text-align: left; padding: 0 10px;}
        .green{background-color: #6B9852;}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table class=""courses-table"">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class=""green"">Posicion</th>
                <th class=""green"">Nombre del Candidato</th>
                <th class=""green"">Teléfono</th>
                <th class=""green"">E-mail</th>
                <th class=""green"">Profesión</th>
                <th class=""green"">Puesto</th>
                <th class=""green"">Comentario</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class=""description""> Vicepresidencia </td>

                <td class=""description"">  @candidato. </td>
                <td class=""description""> </td>
                <td class=""description""> </td>
                <td class=""description""> </td>
                <td class=""description""> </td>
                <td class=""description""> </td>


            </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>

"

                ,

                IsBodyHtml = true

            };
```

Comment: Creo que tu error esta en la concatenación de la variable.

Comment: lo de fiscalia es un objeto pero no va al tema de la pregutna, y "<td class='description'>" + @candidato + "</td> " si funciono por favor ver mas abajo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba cambiando tu código del **Body** por este:

```
 Body =@" <html lang='en'>
                <head>    
                    <meta content='text/html; charset=utf-8' http-equiv='Content-Type'>
                    <title>
                        Notificacion
                    </title>
                    <style type='text/css'>
                        HTML{background-color: #e8e8e8;}
                        .courses-table{font-size: 12px; padding: 3px; border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0;}
                        .courses-table .description{color: #505050;}
                        .courses-table td{border: 1px solid #D1D1D1; background-color: #F3F3F3; padding: 0 10px;}
                        .courses-table th{border: 1px solid #424242; color: #FFFFFF;text-align: left; padding: 0 10px;}
                        .green{background-color: #6B9852;}
                    </style>
                </head>
                <body>
                    <table class='courses-table'>
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th class='green'>Posicion</th>
                                <th class='green'>Nombre del Candidato</th>
                                <th class='green'>Teléfono</th>
                                <th class='green'>E-mail</th>
                                <th class='green'>Profesión</th>
                                <th class='green'>Puesto</th>
                                <th class='green'>Comentario</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td class='description'> Vicepresidencia </td>"+
                                "<td class='description'>" + @candidato + "</td> " +
                                "<td class='description'></td>" +
                                "<td class='description'></td>" +
                                "<td class='description'></td>" +
                                "<td class='description'></td>" +
                                "<td class='description'></td>"+
                            "</tr>"+
                        "</tbody>"+
                    "</table>"+
                "</body>"+
            "</html>";
```

El error esta en que estas mandando una variable pero al momento de concatenarla en el `string` de tu **body** la sigues mandando como **string**, tienes que concatenar el dato que llega. asi :

```
"<td class='description'>  " + @candidato + "</td>"
```

Espero sea de ayuda.

Comment: Podrías explicar por favor, que devuelve `@candidato` ?. Según la pregunta se quiere concatenar el valor de `candidato.nombre`. Y por otra parte, has probado a compilar con esa "@", compila?

Comment: @RafaelAcosta no sabría explicarte que devuelve `@cantidato` ya que es una variable que agrego el OP, supongo que es una variable en la cual llega el objeto o el nombre del candidato. si te fijas en el código que el OP agrego en su pregunta esta la variable definida de esta forma solo con un punto al final `@candidato.`  no lo edite ya que solo esta preguntando por que no llega el dato. asi de simple. y gracias por tu voto negativo.

Comment: De nada, y gracias a tí por tu voto negativo a mi respuesta, que es realmente la correcta. Lo que intento explicar es que tu respuesta está valorada y marcada como correcta, y no es así. Lo digo por que estas cosas pueden llevar a confusiones en los usuarios que consulten este sitio y presuponer que no nos tomamos en serio esto. Gracias.

Comment: Gracias Francisco tu comentario soluciono el problema , canditado es el objeto a insertar en el template se accede mediante razor candidato.x es la propiedad de la clase .Efectivamente el problema con la concatenacion .

Comment: Tengo una consulta ,este template lo estoy realizando desde la logica del controlador , existe la forma de cargar una vista y enviarla por correo o otra forma ?

Comment: Si claro existe otra forma de enviar correos, creando la pagina aparte y llamando variables `[variable]` de esa forma  en html.

Answer (score 1):

puede intentar agregándolo con {} dentro de tu contenido

ejemplo:

```
Body =$"<td class='description'> {candidato.nombre} </td>";
```

Comment: Es una buena respuesta, es otra alternativa válida a string.Format().

Comment: Tambien me funciono muchas gracias .

Answer (score -1):

Una solución válida es utilizar `string.Format()` :

```
Body = string.Format(@" ... <td class=""description"">  {0} </td> ...  ", candidato.nombre)
```

`@candidato.nombre`, sin la **@**.

Si lo que intentas hacer con **@candidato.nombre** es que **Razor** te lo sustituya por su valor equivalente, además de que no se puede hacer, estás violando los principios básicos del paradigma MVC.

Acceder al valor de las variables mediante la directiva **@**, solo lo puedes hacer desde la Vista Razor, y tu lo pretendes hacer desde el Controlador.

Comment: Tengo una consulta ,este template lo estoy realizando desde la logica del contralador , existe la forma de cargar una vista y enviarla por correo o otra forma ?

Comment: porque consideras que es incorrecta ?puedes compartirnos una mejor manera de relizarlo ? de antemano gracias

Comment: @MarceloMP: Has leído mi respuesta?. Yo siendo tú, formularía otra nueva pregunta con la nueva duda que tienes, y corregiría esta.